# Use component @Input as injected service constructor param - or use ServiceFactory pattern instead?

Tags: angular, typescript

in Angular 12 I have a simplified component like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.less']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dataType: string;

  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor(private ds: DataStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.ds.fetchAll();
  }
```

and my simplified DataStorageService looks like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DataStorageService {

  private readonly dataType: string;
  private readonly apiEndpoint: string;

  constructor(dataType: string, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
    this.apiEndpoint = environment.config.urlLogin + '/api/' + this.dataType;
  }

  fetchAll(string) {
    return this.http.get(this.apiEndpoint) as Observable<Item[]>;
  }
```

I want to use

```
<app-list data-type="products">
```

and using *products* as a value in my DataStorageService - without passing it in every function which might make us of it.

I tried injecting it with *useValue* and was thinking about using a ServiceFactory - but I am stuck and don't know how to continue from here.

Especially since *Item* is my generic Type for which I have interface extensions again based on *dataType* string, e.g. *Product extends Item* for dataType *products*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: What if you pass the `dataType` as a parameter for the `fetchAll` method, instead of trying to get the `dataType` on the constructor?

Comment: rephrased question a bit and added info regarding passing the param per method.

Comment: What would the usage of this `app-list` component be? Can you have multiple lists rendered in the same component?

Comment: app-list is more or less an example. I'd like to have my DataStorage behave exactly the same for all functions - the only difference is the api endpoint and the return type extending <Item>. And I'd like to avoid passing "dataType" string for all DataStorage methods.

Comment: I understand, but the solution I am thinking about is going to depend on the fact that you use `app-list` component only once inside another component's template.

Comment: sorry, I'd like to use <app-list> as often as I'd like within a template.

Comment: Then you should probably go for the service factory. Have that build the service for you.

Comment: Sidenote: You need to make sure to have different instances of that service (can't be provided at root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service factory can look something like this:

```
@Injectable(providedIn: 'root')
export class DataServiceFactory {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  
  getDataService(dataType: string): DataStorageService {
    return new DataStorageService(dataType, this.http);
  }
}
```

Then your list component could look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.less']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dataType: string;

  items: Item[] = [];
  private dataService: DataStorageService;

  constructor(private serviceFactory: DataServiceFactory) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService = this.serviceFactory.getDataService(this.dataType);
    this.dataService.fetchAll().subscribe(items => this.items = items);
  }
}
```

Your `DataStorageService` does not even need the `Injectable` decorator at this point, as it will be manually instantiated. You don't rely on the injector to provide it for you.